# object choice field in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to make an ObjectChoice field have fixed length. But by default ObjectChoice length is based on the content length.

For example if the content is "Choice 1", "Choice Choice Choice 1", the ObjectChoice field takes a different length depending on the selected choice.

Answer (score 2):

Use this sample/example:

```
String choices[] = {"0","1","2","3","4"};

ObjectChoiceField choice1 = new ObjectChoiceField("", choices, ""){         
    public void layout(int width, int height){
        width = 80;
        super.layout(getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.layout(width, height);
        setExtent(width, super.getHeight());
    }
};
```